# Cannot resolve corresponding JNI Function | Open CV | Android | Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-ndk, java-native-interface, rx-kotlin

I've successfully compiled and able to run the app into the device, since I am getting this issue trying to use any JNIs function.

Here is the error which I am stuck at -

[image]

Comment: How are you doing the NDK integration? With `externalNativeBuild { cmake {` in your `build.gradle`? Can your show the relevant build scripts?

Comment: Also, the code in your screenshot appears to be Java code, so I'm not sure why the question is tagged [kotlin](?)

Comment: @Michael - Now getting this error `Could not initialize class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.ProtoBuf$PackageFragment`

Comment: @Michael - I am using ndk-build

`externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'Android.mk'
        }
    }`